# Create new fields from existing data in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a field in my Kibana index whose value varies from -100 to 100.

I want to classify data as follows 
If value lies between -100 to -10 it is termed as highly negative.
If value lies between -10 to -2 it is termed as negative.
If value lies between -2 to 2 it is termed as neutral.
and so on.

And I also want the count of how much data is Highly negative, negative or neutral.

Can anyone suggest how can this be done in Kibana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Visualize tab, you can use the range aggregation and define all ranges of interest like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Val.Working Fine now.